# Problema com exibição de hora

Tags: php, javascript

Dae galera, to com um probleminha aqui, tenho a seguinte função:

```
function atualizaHoraServidor() {
  var dispTime = formatarData(digital);

  $('#horarioServidor .horarioRelogio').text(dispTime);

  digital.setSeconds(digital.getSeconds() + 1);

  setTimeout("atualizaHoraServidor()", 1000);
}

function formatarData(data) {
  var options = {
    year: "numeric", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit", second: '2-digit'
};
  return data.toLocaleDateString('pt-br', options);  
}
```

A variável `digital` é criada com o seguinte script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var digital = new Date(<?php echo str_replace(':',', ', str_replace('/',', ', str_replace(' ',', ', date('Y/m/d H:i:s')))).', 0'; ?>); </script>
```

O que esta ocorrendo é que ele esta mostrando a data com 1 mês adiantado, dessa forma: 03/02/2017 11:45:55

Alguém sabe como posso corrigir esse erro?

Já verifiquei a hora do servidor e esta correta.

Comment: De onde vem a variável `digital` em `formatarData(digital);`. No mais, javascript trabalha de `0` até `11` sendo `0` janeiro e `11` dezembro.

Comment: Vem de um script no header: `<script type="text/javascript"> var digital = new Date(<?php echo str_replace(':',', ', str_replace('/',', ', str_replace(' ',', ', date('Y/m/d H:i:s')))).', 0'; ?>); </script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como é possível verificar em:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

O parâmetro mês é de `0` até `11`, sendo `0` janeiro e `11` fevereiro:

> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

Para corrigir o seu problema, basta na criação, subtrair o valor de mês em 1. Ou seja, se o mês for `1`, deve ser utilizado `0`;

Entretanto, seu código está fazendo muito mais que o necessário e criando uma bagunça completa. Existe um meio bem mais simples.

O javascript possui suporte completo ao formato ATOM/RFC3339. Esse formato está definido por constantes da biblioteca [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). Basta utilizá-los

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format(DateTime::ATOM);
```

O exemplo acima irá imprimir:

> 2017-01-03T12:39:58-02:00

Que é o horário atual de Brasília (com horário de verão). No javascript, basta utilizar esse horário:

```
var date = new Date("2017-01-03T12:39:58-02:00");
```

Para fazer a passagem de forma direta, basta apenas:

```
var date = new Date("<?= (new DateTime())->format(DateTime::ATOM) ?>"); // PHP >= 5.4
```

E assim ficará correto para o seu código utilizá-lo qual como tal.

Se o seu PHP não suportar a expressão acima (PHP 5.3), terá que criar variáveis:

```
<?php $date = new DateTime(); ?>
var date = new Date("<?php echo $date->format(DateTime::ATOM) ?>");
```

No mais, é isso.

Pode ver mais no link abaixo
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40916487/php-convert-date-to-javascript-date-january-zero

Comment: Entendi, mas preciso manter o código atual para que outras funções funcionem. É um script de leilão, então ele puxa as informações de data e hora dessa função, para rodar os leilões. Como eu poderia fazer essa subtração?

Comment: Só vai mudar a parte de PHP, o resto continuará igual. Qual vem a ser o problema?

Comment: Hum, não tenho conhecimento nessa área, qual parte devo alterar o que esta no header ou na função?

Comment: No header ta o `var digital = new Date(<?php echo str_replace(':',', ', str_replace('/',', ', str_replace(' ',', ', date('Y/m/d H:i:s')))).', 0'; ?>); `

Comment: @CEW o script no header, aonde a variável `digital` é criada. Substitua toda essa sua linha pelo código que eu lhe passei lá nos exemplos.

Comment: Deu um erro:  syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ',' or ';' in

Comment: Como eu comentei no código acima, sua versão de PHP é muito antiga, use o segundo exemplo, com as variáveis.

Comment: Show de bola, não tava dando certo por que eu não alterei o "date" para "digital", agora funcionou. Valew parceiro, grande abraço e sucesso! ;)