# Função JavaScript para somar dias, está somando um mês pra frente

Tags: javascript

Estou com está função em JavaScript que está somando os dias em uma data,os dias ele soma certo, só que em vez dele somar **24/10/2017 + 2 dias = 26/10/2017**, ele joga um mês pra frente, ai fica assim **24/10/2017 + 2 dias = 26/11/2017.**
segue como eu to fazendo:

```js
 now = new Date;
 var dia_atual = now.getDate();
 var dia_escolha = document.getElementById("<%= txtDiaVencimento.ClientID %>").value;
 if ($("#<%=txtTipodePlano.ClientID %>").val() == "MENSAL") {
     if (parseInt(dia_escolha) > parseInt(dia_atual)) {
         var total_dias = dia_escolha - dia_atual;
         var data_tolerancia;
         var tol = (document.getElementById("<%= txtDiaVencimento.ClientID %>").value);
         var data = toDate(document.getElementById("<%= txtDataInicio.ClientID %>").value);

         function toDate(data) {
             let partes = data.split('/');
             return new Date(partes[2], partes[1], partes[0]);
         }
         data.setDate(data.getDate() + total_dias);
         document.getElementById("<%= txtVencimentoC.ClientID %>").value = data.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
         data.setDate(data.getDate() + parseInt(total_dias));
         document.getElementById("<%= txtDataTolerancia.ClientID %>").value = data.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O mês do objeto Date do JavaScript possui o período entre 0 (Janeiro) e 11 (Dezembro) e não entre 1 e 12.

Logo, no seu cálculo, você pode subtrair o mês do input do usuário em -1.

```
return new Date(partes[2], (partes[1] - 1), partes[0]);
```

Links adicionais:

[MDN - JavaScript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

[Problema com exibição de hora](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174874/problema-com-exibi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-hora/174879#174879)

Comment: Eu não sabia disso, que bom, mas agora funcionou e ficou claro, muito obrigado.